# CasperJS download an Excel file from dialog box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, casperjs

I am new to CasperJS and am trying to download (save to disk) a CSV file, from a dialogue box. Using firefox profile, this would be fairly simple by setting the browser profile properties. Any suggestions how could excel file be downloaded in casperjs ?

`profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",self.opts['output_dir'])
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('application/octet-stream,application/msexcel'))`

I have read links about avoiding  dialog box etc but in this case, it is needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the download() method. See documentation: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download